# Why is ZooKeeper changing the name of my znode?

Tags: flags, apache-zookeeper

I am learning how to use ZooKeeper (version 3.3.3) and have it running with Cygwin (version 1.7.9). In order to create a znode, I do the following:

```
$ zkServer.sh start   
$ zkCli.sh
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] create /zoo-1 "Hello World!" null    
Created /zoo-1
```

This appears to work fine:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /
[zoo-1, zookeeper]
```

However, if I try to use the -s flag this happens:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] create -s /zoo-2 "Hello World!" null
Created /zoo-20000000007
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 3] ls /
[zoo-20000000007, zoo-1, zookeeper]
```

Removing the flag, though, keeps the name the same:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4] create -s /zoo-2 "Hello World!" null
Created /zoo-2
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 5] ls /
[zoo-2, zoo-20000000007, zoo-1, zookeeper]
```

Why does using the -s flag, which makes the znode persistent, also change the name of the znode? I was following along the following tutorial http://java.dzone.com/articles/zookeeper-primer, and from his example the same thing does not happen to him.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the -s flag is to create a [sequential node](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Sequence+Nodes+--+Unique+Naming).  The dzone article looks like it has a mistake.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: No flag creates a normal, persistent node. `-e` creates ephemeral node, which will disappear when the client closes the session.